# How to find the odd rows from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd

student_dict = {
"ID":[101,102,103,104,105,101,102,103,104,105,106,107],
"Student":["AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","YYY","ZZZ"],
"Mark":[50,100,99,60,80,50,100,99,60,80,100,80],
"Address":["St.AAA","St.BBB","St.CCC","St.DDD","St.EEE","St.AAA","St.BBB","St.CCC","St.DDD","St.EEE","St.AYE","St.ZZZ"],
"PhoneNo":[1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444,5555555555,1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444,5555555555,6666666666,7777777777]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(student_dict)
#print(df)
rmv = df.drop_duplicates()
print(rmv)

    ID Student  Mark Address     PhoneNo
0  101     AAA    50  St.AAA  1111111111
1  102     BBB   100  St.BBB  2222222222
2  103     CCC    99  St.CCC  3333333333
3  104     DDD    60  St.DDD  4444444444
4  105     EEE    80  St.EEE  5555555555
5  101     AAA    50  St.AAA  1111111111
6  102     BBB   100  St.BBB  2222222222
7  103     CCC    99  St.CCC  3333333333
8  104     DDD    60  St.DDD  4444444444
9  105     EEE    80  St.EEE  5555555555
10 106     YYY   100  St.AYE  6666666666
11 107     ZZZ    80  St.ZZZ  7777777777
```

Most of the rows are duplicates, except `ID 106 & ID 107`

I tried `df.drop_duplicates()`

```
     ID Student  Mark Address     PhoneNo
0   101     AAA    50  St.AAA  1111111111
1   102     BBB   100  St.BBB  2222222222
2   103     CCC    99  St.CCC  3333333333
3   104     DDD    60  St.DDD  4444444444
4   105     EEE    80  St.EEE  5555555555
10  106     YYY   100  St.AYE  6666666666
11  107     ZZZ    80  St.ZZZ  7777777777
```

it removed the duplicates.

But I need only the odd rows like,

```
 ID Student  Mark Address     PhoneNo
106     YYY   100  St.AYE  6666666666
107     ZZZ    80  St.ZZZ  7777777777
```

is there any way to find the odd rows from a dataframe without passing any values(like ID,Student... from the student_dict) Or is there any inbuild function to find these odd rows?

Comment: What do you mean by "*odd rows*"? What is the explicit expected output?

Comment: `ID Student  Mark Address     PhoneNo`
`106     YYY   100  St.AYE  6666666666`
`107     ZZZ    80  St.ZZZ  7777777777`

Comment: So you just want to remove all duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(df)

     ID Student  Mark Address     PhoneNo
10  106     YYY   100  St.AYE  6666666666
11  107     ZZZ    80  St.ZZZ  7777777777
```